# ion-spinner while waiting for music to load

Tags: angular, ionic2

In my music app, I have a "click" function that makes an http request and plays the .mp3 file from the server. My problem is that sometimes it takes a while for the app to get the audio from the server that is why I added an ion-spinner. I would like the spinner to show up only while the audio is loading and then disappear.

**Home.html**

```
<ion-card-content (click)="play(sound)">
      <div class="wrapper">
      <ion-spinner class="color-green" name="{{ sound.spinner }}"></ion-spinner>
      <img src="{{ sound.imageUrl }}" />       
      </div>     

    </ion-card-content>
```

**Home.ts**

```
/* Plays a sound, pausing other playing sounds if necessary */
  play(sound) {



console.log(sound)
if(this.media) {      
  this.media.pause();      
}
this.media = new Audio(sound.file);    
this.media.load();
this.media.play();
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Home.ts add the below code

```
<ion-card-content (click)="play(sound)">
      <div class="wrapper">
      <ion-spinner class="color-green" [name]="sound.spinner" [paused]="toggleSpinner"></ion-spinner>
      <img src="{{ sound.imageUrl }}" />       
      </div>     

    </ion-card-content>
```

In constructor

```
toggleSpinner= false

 play(sound) {
    toggleSpinner= true
 ......
 }
```

Comment: Aravind, thanks for the response. The loading show up now, but does not disappear. It does not go back to "false" after done loading. Thank you

Comment: can you elaborate?

Comment: When I click on the play button the ion-loading shows up (thats good). After the audio plays the ion-loading is still there when it should be gone. 

So even though the audio has been loaded and played the spinner from ion-loading is still going

Hope that made sense, thank you